# lifetime of IConfigureOptions<T> and IHostingEnvironment implementation service class

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

what is the lifetime of IConfigureOptions and IHostingEnvironment implementation service class from the below :
singleton,scoped,transient,multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IConfigureOptions` is singleton. Here is the [code](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/95b968014f16c3e1b61d1b830022484b9d0db187/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions/OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L72).

`IHostingEnvironment` is obsolete and you [should not use it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

What you should use is `IWebHostEnvironment`, which I am going to assume is also singleton since the MVC testing framework [injects it as singleton](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c8d8cfccffed2001d05098a12cfa00201514aecb/src/Mvc/Mvc/test/MvcServiceCollectionExtensionsTest.cs#L52).

You can easily test how they are injected by just requesting the service multiple times in one request.

- If two consecutive calls to `IServiceProvider::GetService<>()`, return different reference values, then it's transient.
- If they are the same, then it's either scoped or singleton.
- Make another request to your service. If it's still the same, then it's singleton.